# Does boost::asio::io_service preserve the order of handlers?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

Does [`boost::asio::io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html) guarantee that handlers are called in the same order that they are given via [`post()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html)?  I can't find anything saying this in the documentation.  Assume that calls to `io_service::post` are serialized.

Comment: If you are using Boost.Asio then you are definitely too modest, because that's a smart approach to solving a hard problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current implementation does execute things in the sequence you post them, but ordering is only guaranteed for handlers that are explicitly post()ed through a `strand`.

Comment: If there is just 1 worker thread, and ordering is required, do we still require a strand, or strand not needed when 1 worker thread is there?

Answer (score 10):

afaik if you want guaranteed ordering of `post` handler execution you have to use `strand` [as described in the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html).

Comment: If there is just 1 worker thread, and ordering is required, do we still require a strand, or strand not needed when 1 worker thread is there?

Answer (score 0):

~~<del>It seemed for `strand` not to preserve handler execution by the order that you `post` (unlike [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), when you iterate, you iterate the elements by the order that you've inserted them). I think it just ensures those handlers won't be invoked at the same time.</del>~~

See also [How strands guarantee correct execution of pending events in boost.asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097644/how-strands-guarantee-correct-execution-of-pending-events-in-boost-asio)

> strand provides a guarantee for non-concurrency and the invocation order of handlers

In some case, there is no guarantee correct execution if using [io_context::strand::wrap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__strand/wrap.html) (deprecated) or [bind_executor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/bind_executor.html) in `async_op_1(..., s.wrap(a));`. When the async operation completes, the wrapped handler will call `s.dispatch(a)`, but the completion time is uncertain.

> The `io_context::strand` class provides the ability to post and dispatch handlers with the guarantee that none of those handlers will execute concurrently.

See also

- [Asio 1.4.4 / Boost 1.42](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#boost_asio.history.asio_1_4_4___boost_1_42)

  > Documented the guarantee made by strand objects with respect to order of handler invocation.
- [io_context::strand - Order of handler invocation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__strand.html#boost_asio.reference.io_context__strand.order_of_handler_invocation)

  > Note that in the following case:
  >
  > ```
  > async_op_1(..., s.wrap(a));
  > async_op_2(..., s.wrap(b));
  > ```
  >
  > the completion of the first async operation will perform `s.dispatch(a)`, and the second will perform `s.dispatch(b)`, but the order in which those are performed is unspecified. That is, you cannot state whether one happens-before the other. Therefore none of the above conditions are met and no ordering guarantee is made.
- [Timer.5 - Synchronising handlers in multithreaded programs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer5.html)
- [Strands: Use Threads Without Explicit Locking](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html)
- [c++ - boost::io_service How to guarantee handler execution sequence](https://www.ostack.cn/?qa=1033972/)

`strand` provides both the guarantee of not executing completion handlers concurrently and defines the order of handler invocation. In short, completion handlers posted into a `strand` are executed in the same order in which they are posted.

Therefore:

```
strand_.post(&task1);
strand_.post(&task2);
strand_.post(&task3);
```

Guarantees order of handler invocation is `task1` -> `task2` -> `task3`. However, wrapped completion handlers for asynchronous operations are not guaranteed, as the order in which asynchronous operations are performed is unspecified. For example, the following does not provide the same guarantee:

```
async_read(socket1, ..., strand_.wrap(&task1));
async_read(socket2, ..., strand_.wrap(&task2));
async_read(socket3, ..., strand_.wrap(&task3));
```

If completion handlers must be invoked in a specified order for asynchronous operations, then either:

Queue completion handlers and manage the order manually.
Serialize all asynchronous operations. For example, `async_op_1`'s completion handler `task1` initiates `async_op_2` with a completion handler of `task2`.

Here is the relevant excerpt from `io_service::strand`'s order of handler invocation documentation: