# Serialize io_service::post() execution with io_service::run() called only in a single thread

Tags: c++, boost-asio

If I have `io_service::run()` running **only in a single thread**, are `io_service::post()` calls executed in the same order I request them to be executed, or they can be executed in arbitrary order and I still need to use `strand` for forcing serialized execution?

Answer (score 3):

The question has been treated before, e.g.

- [Does boost::asio::io_service preserve the order of handlers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442812/does-boostasioio-service-preserve-the-order-of-handlers)?
- Documentation: [Oreder Of Handler Invocations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service__strand.order_of_handler_invocation)

It clearly spells out

> if any of the following conditions are true:
>
> - `s.post(a)` happens-before `s.post(b)`
> - ...
>
> then `asio_handler_invoke(a1, &a1)` happens-before `asio_handler_invoke(b1, &b1)`.

Note that a single IO thread creates the *implicit strand*  (docs)

---

**Note** In relation to the other answer: of course this doesn't hold when the handler invocations are done implicitly on completion of an asynchronous operation.

> Note that in the following case:
>
> ```
> async_op_1(..., s.wrap(a));
> async_op_2(..., s.wrap(b));
> ```
>
> the completion of the first async operation will perform `s.dispatch(a)`, and
>    the second will perform `s.dispatch(b)`, but the order in which those are
>    performed is unspecified. That is, you cannot state whether one
>    *happens-before* the other. Therefore none of the above conditions are met and
>    no ordering guarantee is made.

Comment: ... but it is still guaranteed that invocation is not concurrent. (correct?)

Comment: @Zero only on an (implicit) strand. Which is, when you have only 1 thread `run()`-ing the service or explicitly serialized operations through a `strand`