# How strands guarantee correct execution of pending events in boost.asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

Consider an echo server implemented using Boost.asio.   Read events from connected clients result in blocks of data being placed on to an arrival event queue.   A pool of threads works through these events - for each event, a thread takes the data in the event and echos it back to the connected client.

[image]

As shown in the diagram above, there could be multiple events in the event queue all from a single client.   In order to ensure that these events for a given client are executed and delivered in order, strands are used.   In this case, all events from a given connected client with be executed in a strand for the client.

My question is: how do strands guarantee the correct order of processing of events?   I presume there must be some kind of lock-per-strand, but even that won't be sufficient, so there must be more to it, and I was hoping someone could perhaps explain it our point me to some code which does this?

I found this document:
[How strands work and why you should use them](http://www.crazygaze.com/blog/2016/03/17/how-strands-work-and-why-you-should-use-them/)

It sheds some light on the mechanism, but says that in a strand "Handler execution order is not guaranteed".   Does that mean that we could end up with receiving back "Strawberry forever. fields"?

Also - whenever a new client connects, do we have to create a new strand, so that there is one strand per client?

Finally - when a read event arrives, how do we know which strand to add it to?   The strand has to be looked up form all strands using the connection as a key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`strand` provides a guarantee for non-concurrency and the invocation order of *handlers*; `strand` does not control the order in which *operations* are executed and demultiplexed.  Use a `strand` if you have either:

- multiple threads accessing a shared object that is not thread safe
- a need for a guaranteed sequential ordering of handlers

The `io_service` will provide the desired and expected ordering of buffers being filled or used in the order in which operations are initiated.  For instance, if the `socket` has "Strawberry fields forever." available to be read, then given:

```cpp
buffer1.resize(11); // buffer is a std::vector managed elsewhere
buffer2.resize(7);  // buffer is a std::vector managed elsewhere
buffer3.resize(8);  // buffer is a std::vector managed elsewhere
socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer1), handler1);
socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer2), handler2);
socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer3), handler3);
```

When the operations complete:

- `handler1` is invoked, `buffer1` will contain "Strawberry "
- `handler2` is invoked, `buffer2` will contain "fields "
- `handler3` is invoked, `buffer3` will contain "forever."

However, the order in which the completion handlers are invoked is unspecified.  This unspecified ordering remains true even with a `strand`.

---

### Operation Demultiplexing

Asio uses the Proactor design pattern<sup>[1]</sup> to demultiplex operations.  On most platforms, this is implemented in terms of a Reactor.  The [official documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html) mentions the components and their responsibilities.  Consider the following example:

```cpp
socket.async_read_some(buffer, handler);
```

The caller is the initiator, starting an `async_read_some` asynchronous operation  and creating the `handler` completion handler.  The asynchronous operation is executed by the [StreamSocketService](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/StreamSocketService.html) operation processor:

- Within the initiating function, if the socket has no other outstanding asynchronous read operations and data is available, then StreamSocketService will read from the socket and enqueue the `handler` completion handler into the `io_service`
- Otherwise, the read operation is queued onto the socket, and the reactor is informed to notify Asio once data becomes available on the socket.  When the `io_service` is ran and data is available on the socket, then the reactor will inform Asio.  Next, Asio will dequeue an outstanding read operation from the socket, execute it, and enqueue the `handler` completion handler into the `io_service`

The `io_service` proactor will dequeue a completion handler, demultiplex the handler to threads that are running the `io_service`, from which the `handler` completion handler will be executed.  The order of invocation of the completion handlers is unspecified.

#### Multiple Operations

If multiple operations of the same type are initiated on a socket, it is currently unspecified as to the order in which the buffers will be used or filled.  However, in the current implementation, each socket uses a FIFO queue for each type of pending operation (e.g. a queue for read operations; a queue for write operations; etc).  The [networking-ts](https://cplusplus.github.io/networking-ts/draft.pdf) draft, which is based partially on Asio, specifies:

> the `buffers` are filled in the order in which these operations were issued. The order of invocation of the completion handlers for these operations is unspecified.

Given:

```cpp
socket.async_read_some(buffer1, handler1); // op1
socket.async_read_some(buffer2, handler2); // op2
```

As `op1` was initiated before `op2`, then `buffer1` is guaranteed to contain data that was received earlier in the stream than the data contained in `buffer2`, but `handler2` may be invoked before `handler1`.

#### Composed Operations

Composed operations are composed of zero or more intermediate operations. For example, the [`async_read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) composed asynchronous operation is composed of zero or more intermediate `stream.async_read_some()` operations.

The current implementation uses operation chaining to create a continuation, where a single `async_read_some()` operation is initiated, and within its internal completion handle, it determines whether or not to initiate another `async_read_some()` operation or to invoke the user's completion handler.  Because of the continuation, the `async_read` documentation requires that no other reads occur until the composed operation completes:

> The program must ensure that the stream performs no other read operations (such as `async_read`, the stream's `async_read_some` function, or any other composed operations that perform reads) until this operation completes.

If a program violates this requirement, one may observe interwoven data, because of the aforementioned order in which buffers are filled.

For a concrete example, consider the case where an `async_read()` operation is initiated to read 26 bytes of data from a socket:

```cpp
buffer.resize(26); // buffer is a std::vector managed elsewhere
boost::asio::async_read(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer), handler);
```

If the socket receives "Strawberry ", "fields ", and then "forever.", then the `async_read()` operation may be composed of one or more `socket.async_read_some()` operations.  For instance, it could be composed of 3 intermediate operations:

- The first `async_read_some()` operation reads 11 bytes containing "Strawberry " into the buffer starting at an offset of 0.  The completion condition of reading 26 bytes has not been satisfied, so another `async_read_some()` operation is initiated to continue the operation
- The second `async_read_some()` operation reads 7 byes containing "fields " into the buffer starting at an offset of 11.  The completion condition of reading 26 bytes has not been satisfied, so another `async_read_some()` operation is initiated to continue the operation
- The third `async_read_some()` operation reads 8 byes containing "forever." into the buffer starting at an offset of 18.  The completion condition of reading 26 bytes has been satisfied, so `handler` is enqueued into the `io_service`

When the `handler` completion handler is invoked, `buffer` contains "Strawberry fields forever."

---

### Strand

[`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) is used to provide serialized execution of *handlers* in a guaranteed order.  Given:

- a strand object `s`
- a function object `f1` that is added to strand `s` via `s.post()`, or `s.dispatch()` when `s.running_in_this_thread() == false`
- a function object `f2` that is added to strand `s` via `s.post()`, or `s.dispatch()` when `s.running_in_this_thread() == false`

then the strand provides a guarantee of ordering and non-concurrency, such that `f1` and `f2` will not be invoked concurrently.  Furthermore, if the addition of `f1` happens before the addition of `f2`, then `f1` will be invoked before `f2`.

With:

```cpp
auto wrapped_handler1 = strand.wrap(handler1);
auto wrapped_handler2 = strand.wrap(handler2);
socket.async_read_some(buffer1, wrapped_handler1); // op1
socket.async_read_some(buffer2, wrapped_handler2); // op2
```

As `op1` was initiated before `op2`, then `buffer1` is guaranteed to contain data that was received earlier in the stream than the data contained in `buffer2`, but the order in which the `wrapped_handler1` and  `wrapped_handler2` will be invoked is unspecified.  The `strand` guarantees that:

- `handler1` and `handler2` will not be invoked concurrently
- if `wrapped_handler1` is invoked before `wrapped_handler2`, then `handler1` will be invoked before `handler2`
- if `wrapped_handler2` is invoked before `wrapped_handler1`, then `handler2` will be invoked before `handler1`

Similar to the composed operation implementation, the `strand` implementation uses operation chaining to create a continuation.  The `strand` manages all handlers posted to it in a FIFO queue.  When the queue is empty and a handler is posted to the strand, then the strand will post an internal handle to the `io_service`.  Within the internal handler, a handler will be dequeued from the `strand`'s FIFO queue, executed, and then if the queue is not empty, the internal handler posts itself back to the `io_service`.

Consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857101) answer to find out how a composed operation uses [`asio_handler_invoke()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asio_handler_invoke.html) to wrap intermediate handlers within the same context (i.e. `strand`) of the completion handler.  The implementation details can be found in the comments on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016135).

---

<sup>1. [POSA2] D. Schmidt et al, Pattern Oriented Software Architecture, Volume 2. Wiley, 2000.</sup>

Answer (score 8):

A strand is an execution context which executes handlers within a critical section, on a correct thread.

That critical section is implemented (more or less) with a mutex.

It's a little cleverer than that because if a dispatcher detects that a thread is already in the strand, it appends the handler to a queue of handlers to be executed before the critical section has been left, but after the current handler has completed.

thus in this case the new handler is 'sort of' posted to the currently executing thread.

There are some guarantees in ordering.

```
strand::post/dispatch(x);
strand::post/dispatch(y);
```

will always result in x happening before y.

but if x dispatches a handler z during its execution, then the execution order will be:

x, z, y

note that the idiomatic way to handle io completion handlers with strands is not to post work to a strand in the completion handler, but to wrap the completion handler in the strand, and do the work there.

asio contains code to detect this and will do the right thing, ensuring correct ordering and eliding un-necessary intermediate posts.

e.g.:

```
async_read(sock, mystrand.wrap([](const auto& ec, auto transferred)
{
  // this code happens in the correct strand, in the correct order.
});
```

Comment: I like this fresh take, slightly different vantage point. I think it adds insight [I admit a lot of the appeal is the brevity. It's just easier for me to grasp & recall :). @TannerSansbury, do you see any problems with this as a highlevel mental model?]

Comment: @sehe I feel that asio needs more of this brief but to-the point documentation. The existing documentation took me ages to master, simply because there are so many subtle side-effects that are incredibly important.

Comment: @sehe I too like the brevity of this answer and think it works fines as a mental model.  My only concern is that I feel the current wording incorrectly implies that one _must_ use a `strand` to obtain the correct ordering.

Comment: @TannerSansbury I didn't mean to imply that, only that it's more idiomatic. I feel the one thing that asio lacks is a "weak_bind" which would bind a handler to both a strand and a weak_ptr, only executing if the pointer can be locked. This would tidy up asio code which uses persistent callbacks while avoiding circular references.

Comment: @Richard I suspected that you did not mean to imply that.  For me, I read "asio contains code to detect this and will do the right thing, ensuring correct ordering" as having two potential interpretations: one being that Asio will continue to ensure the correct ordering of data with `strand.wrap()`, and the other being that one only obtains the correct ordering of data when using `strand.wrap()`.